# Linux SELINUX CONTEXTS and LABELING

Tags: ssh, selinux, home

Until recently I came across a situation where I was working with automount with non nfs protocol storage type `ie Fsx Lustre` in AWS where I found a weird issue on the automounted home directories and whenever users are trying to set up key-less access with their public keys, Selinux just dispelling it out as Selinux is in `enforcing` mode.

While investigating later on I found the context on the home_dir is `undefined` and `unlabeled` thus key based access was simply denied.

However, I tried to recover it with `restorecon -R -v ~` but it didn't work and then I recognized it will not work while Selinux is in `enforcing` mode, So, I used `chcon` and that worked for me.

However, `chcon` works but I see the remark in the RedHat Doc as changes made with the `chcon command do not survive a file system relabel` but i could not understand it completely though it says `chcon` for Temporary changes however, again it survives across reboot and log off login for me.

### Issue:

```
drwx------. myuser mygrp  unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 .ssh
```

### Fix:

Below is the command what i used and that fixed the issue.

```
$ chcon -R unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0  /home/<user_name>/.ssh/
```

### Alternative:

However, Below will be more succinct over `chcon`.

```
$ semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t /path/to/users/homedirectory/.ssh/
$ restorecon -v /path/to/users/homedirectory/.ssh/
```

Any explanation will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try recursively

```
$ semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/path/to/users/homedirectory(/.*)?"
$ restorecon -Rv /path/to/users/homedirectory/
```